# A11y displaying data to the user with the use of section

Tags: html, accessibility

Say that I am creating a display of the user's data and I wish to make this as accessible as possible.

in the documentation, it says that each section should be followed by a heading for that section. So if I wanted to edit the HTML (shown below):

```html
<h1> User data </h1>
<h2> see user data below </h2>
<div>
  <h3> First name </h3>
  <p> Marc </p>
</div>
<div>
  <h3> Last name </h3>
  <p> MyLastName </p>
</div>
```

Would you use the `<section>` tag instead of the `div` that encapsulates the data or would that be an overuse of the tag `<section>` also would it be correct to have all the "field tags" such as `firstname` & `lastname` as `h3` or should the decent?

Comment: This should probably be a list, table or `readonly` inputs with labels. It doesn't make much sense to have field entries under different headings. Could you explain a little more about the data (is it user entered, is the information from one form or multiple places, is this a check of data that has been entered etc.) My gut reaction is that this should be a form with readonly inputs as it is displaying back what looks to be user data, but that is just my gut, there isn't enough info.

Comment: At first glance, I would say that it's an overuse of headings. You should probably not use headings for paragraphs that are just a few words or a single short sentence long. A list (either UL, OR or DL) is probably better suited here.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie it is basically a document that shows all of the users information this includes name, address, birthday etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @QuentinC pointed out in the comments and given the information you gave I would recommend using a [Description List element (`<dl>`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl)

This allows you to create a list of items with descriptions.

The beauty of this is you can use further semantic elements to markup the address, DOB etc.

You can also style them as if they were standard divs (although you have to remove margin as the `<dd>` element has margin in the user agent style sheet) so you can do side by side etc.

I also added an extra `<p>` between your `<h1>` and `<h2>` as they should not be next to each other. I assume this was just your example to keep it succinct but I brought attention to it just in case you were not aware and this was how your end document was structured.

An example of this would be:

```css
dl dt{
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 10px 0;
}
dl dd{
   float: left;
   width: 50%;
   margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<h1> User data </h1>

<p>There should be text here otherwise the &lt;h2&gt; should actually just be a paragraph, headings should not be right next to each other</p>

<h2> see user data below </h2>

<dl>
    <dt>First name</dt>
    <dd>Marc</dd>

    <dt>Last name</dt>
    <dd>MyLastName</dd>

    <dt>Address</dt>
    <dd><address> Mozilla Foundation<br>
    331 E Evelyn Ave<br>
    Mountain View, CA 94041<br>
    USA</address> </dd>
    
    <dt>Date of Birth</dt>
    <dd><time datetime="1990-05-15">May 15 1990</time></dd>
    
</dl>
```